# Going from numerical month to Gregorian name for month

Tags: objective-c

Currently I'm using the following code to acquire a date from a date picker. Right now, when I NSLog the NSDateComponents var, I get the numberical representation for a month (i.e. 7 for July). How can I print out the Month name, as well as the day of the week, like Saturday?

```
   NSDate *selectedDate = _datePicker.date;

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM:DD:HH:mm"];

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:_datePicker.date];

    NSLog(@"components: %@",components);
```

Comment: Why are you using a date formatting and date components? Do you actually need both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the format strings `EEEE` for the day of the week, and `MMMM` for the month of the year in your `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: sweet thanks. Also, is there a way to not use military time with the NSDateFormatter?

Comment: For 12-hour time formats, use `h` (rather than `H`) to print the hour, and `a` to print the "AM" or "PM" period. For a complete list of possible symbols (with examples), see: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-17.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

Comment: FYI (and this seldom really matters): the UTS link is for v17 of the spec, which was used for OS X 10.7 and iOS 4.3. They've upgraded to later versions of the spec since then. You can see which version of the spec each OS version uses in the Data Formatting Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1 For example, in v25 there is better handling of the Chinese lunar calendar and ISO 8601 time zones. (This stuff tends to be obscure, but can be nice to know.)

Answer (score 2):

You might use `monthSymbols` from `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDate *selectedDate = _datePicker.date;
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:selectedDate];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *month = [[dateFormatter monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:components.month - 1];
```